# Function is Baire-1 if and only if these sets are $F_\sigma$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, continuity

I AM LOOKING FOR A HINT, NOT A FULL SOLUTION, TO THE FOLLOWING PROBLEM:

> A function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is called Baire-1 if it is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions. Prove that a function $f$ is Baire-1 if and only if the sets $\{ x: f(x) > c \}$ and $\{x: f(x) < c \}$ are $F_\sigma$ sets for each real number $c$.

I have no intuition with these concepts. I would very much appreciate a hint.

I would even further appreciate if someone could outline how I can play around with questions like these. I find non-analysis problems much easier to play around with and gain intuition about and I would like to gain a similar ability for analysis.

Comment: Useful references for such results besides advanced level descriptive set theory texts: Frank A. Ballone's 2010 Masters thesis [**On Volterra Spaces**](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/!etd.send_file?accession=ysu1288364649), Abhijit Dasgupta's 2014 book [**Set Theory. With an Introduction to Real Point Sets**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01182627S), Chapter XV in Natanson's 1960 book (or any earlier edition) [**Theory of Functions of a Real Variable**, Volume II](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0019CL610), **(continued)**

Comment: Chapter 5 in Russell A. Gordon's 1994 book [**The Integrals of Lebesgue, Denjoy, Perron, and Henstock**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0821838059), Chapter 7 (among others also probably relevant) in John C. Oxtoby's 1980 book (or 1971 1st ed.) [**Measure and Category**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387905081), Sections 10.4-10.5 in Bruckner/Bruckner/Thomson's 2008 book (or 10.3-10.4 in the 1997 1st ed.) [**Real Analysis**](http://www.classicalrealanalysis.info/com/Real-Analysis.php), Section 11 in van-Rooij/Schikhof's 1982 book [**A Second Course on Real ...**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0521283612).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro can the codomain in the theorem above be changed to any metric space Y? Because I still can not found the theorem above with codomains other than $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user134340: The problem is how to interpret $f(x) > c$ when the values $f(x)$ belong to a metric space. Do we consider linearly (= totally) ordered metric spaces of some type, or use some other relation that captures a similar idea more abstractly (e.g. in a normed space, use $|f(x)| > c),$ or something else? I'm sure there must be types of generalizations along these lines somewhere in the literature, but I'm not aware of anything right now.

Comment: @user134340: If you're only looking for a criterion that works for more general codomains, maybe Theorem (24.3) on p. 190 in [**Classical Descriptive Set Theory**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387943749) by Alexander S. Kechris (1995), a result that was likely known since the 1920s and can probably also be found in Kuratowski's Topology treatise (probably even [the 1933 1st edition](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.zamlynska-9ee68a27-f16a-4074-a332-1d8b3b83f2a7?q=bwmeta1.element.dl-catalog-80f4c443-e772-4939-9305-45fe3beb92ec;2&qt=CHILDREN-STATELESS)).

Answer (score 0):

**Small Hint:**  the sets that you are asked to prove something about are open sets, and open sets can be written as the countable union of closed sets (i.e. $F_{\sigma}$ sets).  Each of those sets can then be viewed as part of a sequence of functions that you can take a limit of.

**Slightly larger hint:** the open interval $(a,b)$ can be written as $\cup_{n\in {\mathbb N}}[a+1/n,b-1/n]$ and we can define functions $f_n$ by $\{x: f_n(x) \geq c+\frac{1}{n} \}$

For general intuition: this is something that tends to come with time.  I found I needed to think *a lot* about these kinds of things before I had a library of tools that let me look at something and know where to start.  Hunting for counter-examples tends to help a great deal as it forces you to really understand what you're trying to work with, and finding them can help direct you towards the right route when you get stuck on other problems.

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't that be
$$
(a,b) = \bigcup_{n\in {\mathbb N}}[a+1/n,b-1/n] \text{?}
$$

Comment: Also, I don't understand the definition of $f_n$ . The right-hand side is a set?

Comment: @eudes thanks for catching those -- yes, the signs were the wrong way round, and yes, the $:=$ should have been the word $by$ :)