# Baire Class Function

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the  characteristic function X, over the closed bounded set F, belongs to Baire class one.

I have calculated the Lebesgue sets E(X>k) and E(X

Comment: See my comments to [Function is Baire-1 if and only if these sets are $F_\sigma$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3198802/13130) for several useful references about Borel sets and Baire sets directed towards those studying real analysis.

Comment: **Hint:** The complement of $F$ can be written as a countable union of closed sets (note that the complement is an open set ...), and without loss of generality we can assume the complement is the union over positive integers $n$ of closed sets $C_n$ such that for each $n$ we have $C_n \subseteq C_{n+1}$ (i.e. write $F$ as an increasing union of closed sets). For each $n$ we have that $F$ and $C_n$ are disjoint closed sets. Use Urysohn's lemma to define a continuous function $f_n$ that is identically $1$ on $F$ and identically $0$ on $C_n.$ Show that $f_n$ converges pointwise to . . .